# Proof formula of Proof by Contradiction $[ (\neg p \implies q) \land (\neg p\implies \neg q)] \implies p$

Tags: logic, proof-verification

> I would like to prove the following statement :
>   $$[  (\neg p \implies q) \land (\neg p\implies \neg q)] \implies p$$
>
> - I'm interested in others ways of proving that

**My Proof:**

- **Method** $1$:

Let $ R: [  (\neg p \implies q) \land (\neg p\implies \neg q)]$

Suppose that $R$ is true

\begin{align}
 R &\iff [  (\neg p \implies q) \land (\neg p\implies \neg q)]  \\
 R &\iff ( p  \lor q) \land ( p \lor \neg q) \\
 R &\iff  p  \lor ( q \land \neg q) \\
 R &\iff  p \lor \bot \\
 R &\iff  p
\end{align}
 - **Method** $2$:

Let $ R: [  (\neg p \implies q) \land (\neg p\implies \neg q)]$

Suppose that $R$ is true
\begin{align}
  R &\iff ( p  \lor q) \land ( p \lor \neg q) \\
  R &\iff ( p \land p) \lor ( p \land \neg q ) \lor ( q \land p) \lor ( q \land      \neg q)\\
  R &\iff p \lor ( p \land \neg q ) \lor ( q \land p) \lor \bot \\
  R &\iff p \lor ( p \land \neg q ) \lor ( q \land p) \\
  R &\implies p \lor ( q \lor \neg q )  \\
  R &\implies  p \lor \bot \\
  R &\implies  p
 \end{align}
i used for that line : $$p \lor ( p \land \neg q ) \lor ( q \land p)  \implies p \lor ( q \lor \neg q )$$
[image]

- Is my proof correct for both method if not would you explain me why and correct it

Update:

Method $2$:

\begin{align}
  R &\iff ( p  \lor q) \land ( p \lor \neg q) \\
  R &\iff ( p \land p) \lor ( p \land \neg q ) \lor ( q \land p) \lor ( q \land      \neg q)\\
  R &\iff p \lor ( p \land \neg q ) \lor ( q \land p) \lor \bot \\
  R &\iff p \lor ( p \land \neg q ) \lor ( q \land p) \\
  R &\implies p \lor ( q \lor \neg q )  \\
  R &\implies  p \lor \top \\
  R &\implies  p
 \end{align}
am i right since i used the argument $p\land q \implies p$

Answer (score 3):

Method 1 is correct method 2 has a flaw in the third to last line.
\begin{align}
  R &\iff p \lor ( p \land \neg q ) \lor ( q \land p) \\
\end{align}
is equivalent with
\begin{align}
  R &\iff p \lor (p \land (\neg q  \lor  q)) \\
\end{align}
Which in turn can be transformed to
\begin{align}
  R &\iff p \lor (p \land \top) \\
   R &\iff p \lor p \\
   R &\iff p \\
\end{align}
Thus we are done. What should tip you off in your solution is the fact that $q\vee \neg q $ is equivalent with $\top$ not $\bot$.

Comment: am i wrong using the argument $(p \land q) \implies p$

Comment: No you are not. However it does not get you anywhere. In this case instead of getting an equivalent expression, you get $q\vee \neg q$ which is equivalent to $\top$, and this will not lead you to $p$. The only fault in your argument is really that $(q\vee \neg q)$ is equivalent with $\bot$.

Comment: see my update please

Comment: With the update, the faulty step is that $p\vee \top$ implies $p$. The only thing which $p\vee \top$ leads to is $\top$, which is not the same as $p$.

Comment: so i have to follow the same principale of method 1

Comment: In some sence, yes, or at least using the $(p\wedge q)\Rightarrow p$ will not lead you anywhere, since it gives you something which is not equivalent and even it gives you something which is "more true", thus you will never reach something is equivalent with your original expression if you use this rule.

Comment: Thanks so much just one last question $(p\land T)\implies p$ if p true

Comment: Well, yes $(p\wedge \top )\Rightarrow p$ if $p$ true, since then it actually say $(\top \wedge top)\Rightarrow \top$. However If we have not fixated $p$ as true, then this does not hold.